# Calculating upper bound for multivariate Taylor's theorem

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, newton-raphson, hessian-matrix

We have a system of linear equations 
$f_1 ...f_d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, such that $f_i(x_1 , x_2 ,..., x_d)=0$ for $i=1,...,d$ (click image for main question) [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQjz1.jpg)

I have managed to do the first part of this question, but for bounding $||R||_2$ I ended up with a double sum of all the elements of $(\textbf{x} - \textbf{y})$ being multiplied together which is clearly a lot larger than $||\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}||_2^2$ like this: [My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkOuM.jpg) after using the Hessian and Taylor series.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
\begin{align*}
f_{i}(y)=f_{i}(y)-f_{i}(x)=D^{1}f_{i}(x)[y-x]+\dfrac{1}{2}D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})[y-x,y-x],~~~~x=(x_{1},...,x_{d}),
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
f(y)&=(f_{1}(y),...,f_{d}(y))\\
&=D^{1}f(x)[y-x]+\dfrac{1}{2}\left(D^{2}f_{1}(z_{1})[y-x,y-x],...,D^{2}f_{d}(z_{d})[y-x,y-x]\right),
\end{align*}
where $D^{1}f(x)$ is the canonical matrix which rows are defined by $D^{1}f_{i}(x)$, $i=1,...,d$ respectively.

Now
\begin{align*}
&\left\|\left(D^{2}f_{1}(z_{1})[y-x,y-x],...,D^{2}f_{d}(z_{d})[y-x,y-x]\right)\right\|_{2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\bigg|D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})[y-x,y-x]\bigg|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\left\|D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})[y-x]\right\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}\|y-x\|_{2}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\|D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}\|y-x\|_{2}^{4}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\|D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\|y-x\|_{2}^{2},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\|D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}\color{red}\leq\sum_{m,n=1}^{d}\left|\dfrac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{m}\partial x_{n}}(z_{i})\right|^{2}\leq K^{2}d^{2}.
\end{align*}

Note that $D^{1}f_{i}(x)=\left(\dfrac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{1}}(x),...,\dfrac{f_{i}}{\partial x_{d}}(x)\right)$, $D^{1}f(x)$ is the matrix which the first row is $D^{1}f_{1}(x)$,..., and the last row is $D^{1}f_{d}(x)$.

$D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})$ is the Hessian matrix, $D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})[y-x,y-x]$ is like $[y-x]^{T}D^{2}f_{i}(z_{i})[y-x]$.

Actually we have for a square matrix $A$, $\|Ax\|_{2}\leq\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{d}|x_{i}|\|Ae_{i}\|_{2}\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\|Ae_{i}\|_{2}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\|x\|_{2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d}|a_{ij}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\|x\|_{2}$, so $\|A\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}\leq\displaystyle\sum_{i,j=1}^{d}|a_{i,j}|^{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about D^1 and D^2 please? I don't think I've seen that matrix before. Is it a standard definition?

Comment: $z_{i}$ is the point lies between $x$ and $y$, somehow it is like the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: The term like $[u,v]$ means, for fixed $u$, the map $v\rightarrow D^{2}[u,v]$ is linear (so it is a linear map with variable $v$), likewise, for fixed $v$, the map $u\rightarrow D^{2}[u,v]$ is linear.

Comment: Finally could you explain what the notation $||...||_{2→2}^2$ means?

Comment: It is the operator norm, for example, if $T:l^{2}\rightarrow l^{2}$ is a linear operator, then $\|T\|_{2\rightarrow 2}$ is defined by $\|T\|_{2\rightarrow 2}=\sup_{x\ne 0, x\in l^{2}}\dfrac{\|Tx\|_{2}}{\|x\|_{2}}$, in particular, we have $\|Tx\|_{2}\leq\|T\|_{2\rightarrow 2}\|x\|_{2}$, of course, then we have $\|Tx\|_{2}^{2}\leq\|T\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}\|x\|_{2}^{2}$.

Comment: And one further point here: For a square matrix $A$, if we associate it with the corresponding linear operator $T:x\rightarrow Ax$, then essentially $\|T\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{i,j}|^{2}$, which means it is just the square sum of all of its entries. Further, if we associate the linear operator $S$ of the form $S:x\rightarrow x^{T}A$, then it is still true that $\|S\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}$ equals to the square sum of its entries.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. So is this the reasoning that gives our op norm <= K^2 * D^2 $ ? Is there a short proof for this result or is it more involved?

Comment: Also, did you drop a square root around the term in brackets on the line above "where"?

Comment: Yes, I accidentally dropped it, thanks. The operator norm should be less than or equal to $KD$, because I wrote $\|\cdot\|_{2\rightarrow 2}^{2}$, the operator norm is designated to $\|\cdot\|_{2\rightarrow 2}$. I fail to figure out simpler solution, sorry about that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the operator norm being the square sum of entries? I thought 2-norm was usually defined in terms of largest singular value.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I messed up my own, the $2\rightarrow 2$ operator norm is NOT necessarily the square sum, but it can be controlled by that, I have updated the details.

Comment: But one further point: In the space of matrices, one used to define the topology regarding the square root of square sum of its entries, that's why I messed up, of course you can define the $2\rightarrow 2$ operator norm as a topology, but the point is, any norm topologies for the finite dimensional space are equivalent in the sense that the values of the norms are not exactly the same but they can be controlled by each other by a constant, in this case, $2\rightarrow 2$ norm is controlled by the square root square sum norm with constant $1$. For the other direction, some constant is needed.

Comment: And one point here, your question is not asking for best bound, and it is freely for you to find any bound for it, so controlling $2\rightarrow 2$ bound by the square root square sum bound is just fine.